# Adding to the tail of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have an append method for my linked list where I want to add to the tail, however when a new node is added to the list, headNode and tailNode both become the newly inserted node. How do I keep headNode to stay as the first node that was entered into the list and not have it become the same thing as tailNode.

```
 public static void append()
{
 for(int x = 0; x < gradeArray.length; x++)
 {
   if(gradeArray[x] < 70)
   {
     StudentNode newNode = new StudentNode(nameArray[x], gradeArray[x], null);
     if(headNode == null)
     {
       headNode = newNode;
     }
     else
     {
       tailNode.nextNode = newNode;
     }
     tailNode = newNode;
}
 }
 }
```

Comment: When you call append() are you sure that head node is not reset to null? Can you log the head node and tail node in append method to see whether they are null or not?

Comment: headNode is declared in the class as:   private static StudentNode headNode = null;

Comment: Is it intended that there can be only a single linked list application-wide (because of the `static`)?

Comment: Yes, there is only one linked list

Comment: Do you ever create this class where this method is located more than once? And does the headNode variable ever change anywhere in this class?

Comment: This method is only located once and the headNode does not change anywhere in this class other than in this method.

Comment: @AlexG What about tailNode, is it called anywhere outside this method? It would help if we could see the full class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what mistake are you doing but see below this code is working perfectly fine.

```
    public class Grades {

    public static String[] nameArray = new String[50];
    public static int[] gradeArray = new int[50];

    public static StudentNode headNode;
    public static StudentNode tailNode;

    public static void append() {
        for (int x = 0; x < gradeArray.length; x++) {
            if (gradeArray[x] < 70) {

                String name = nameArray[x];
                int grade = gradeArray[x];
                StudentNode newNode = new StudentNode(name, grade, null);
                if (headNode == null) {
                    headNode = newNode;
                } else {
                    tailNode.nextNode = newNode;
                }
                tailNode = newNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            nameArray[i] = "name-" + i;
            gradeArray[i] = i;
        }

        append();

        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            nameArray[i] = "name-" + (i + 50);
            gradeArray[i] = i + 50;
        }

        append();

        System.out.println(headNode.toString());
        System.out.println(tailNode.toString());
    }
 }

 class StudentNode {

    public int grade;
    public String name;
    public StudentNode nextNode;

    public StudentNode(String n, int g, StudentNode sn) {
        name = n;
        grade = g;
        nextNode = sn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + grade;
    }
}
```

Even if you change grade and name arrays and run append again it still keeps the head correct.

[Ideone link for running code](https://ideone.com/129lTU)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you append this statement ? `tailNode = newNode;`

Imagine, thread goes through by  `if(headNode == null)` he assign newNode adress to headNode . After that, `tailNode = newNode;` is executed and tail pointing to newNode.
Finally, tailNode and headNode point to the same object : newNode.

I think you have to delete this statement `tailNode = newNode;`

Comment: The first added node is and should be head and tail at the same time, this is correct.

Comment: When I take that line out it still does the same thing.